# Nhibernate updating an entity when selecting

Tags: nhibernate

I have this entity:

```
public class Permission 
{
    public virtual int Id{get;set;}
    public virtual string Entity { get; set; }
    public virtual bool ReadAction { get; set; }
    public virtual bool UpdateAction { get; set; }
    public virtual bool CreateAction { get; set; }
    public virtual bool DeleteAction { get; set; }
    public virtual Role Role { get; set; }

    public virtual string RoleName
    {
        get { return Enum.GetName(typeof(Role),this.Role}
    }
}

public class PermissionMap : ClassMap<Permission>
{
    public PermissionMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id, "id").GeneratedBy.Identity().UnsavedValue(0);
        Map(x => x.Entity);
        Map(x => x.DeleteAction).CustomType<BooleanType>();
        Map(x => x.ReadAction).CustomType<BooleanType>();
        Map(x => x.CreateAction).CustomType<BooleanType>();
        Map(x => x.UpdateAction).CustomType<BooleanType>();
        Map(x => x.Role).CustomType<int>();
    }
}

public enum Role 
{
   Administrator = 0,
   SalesPerson = 1,
   Marketing = 2
}
```

Every time I query the database it gets Updated.
I thought it is because of RoleName, but event when I have removed it its still get update.
The Permission get update for each row it has in the database.
Thanks

Comment: What happened is 1) the query is part of transaction *(better, there is Flush() called at the end of the request)* and 2) The mapping does not fit to the DB setting, mostly for null vs not-null columns. So if DB contains nullable boolean, and the value is NULL, the mapping says: it is bool *(not nullable)*... so dirty object in the session ... fix it in DB. Other words, check the nullability of your columns first...

Comment: @RadimKöhler, thanks, I have cleaned all nullable, recreated the schema, and the problem still happening. thanks

Comment: The point is, that we are all the time working with a session. It is *so smart* that even during read operation, it does keep track of all items by their ID. If, any object is changed somehow *(e.g. for a rendering or transfering reasons)* and is still referenced by open session, it is managed as dirty one. When the `session.Fulsh()` is called (usually by default on transaction Commit() or even auto, depends on the FlushMode) any dirty object is persisted. Having this: investigate if you are not changing any object...while having opened session. NHibernate is predictable, this won't be a bug;)

Comment: @RadimKöhler I see what you are saying, and I see that on every entity  that I have enum mapped the problem is happening.  what is wrong with this enum? `Map(x => x.Role).CustomType<int>();` thanks for your time

Comment: I would say: nothing is wrong - with the mapping. The suspected to me, are the values stored in DB. If they are not matching the enum declaration *(there is NULL or let's say -1 or 1000 stored)* then in the runtime, NHibernate will *fix* the value... and it will become dirty. Are you sure, that all the data in DB are (0,1,2) as your enum?

Comment: Just from curiosity point of view 1) via the BooleanType in the mapping? it could be omitted I'd say... 2) I would check all the mapping (switching them off) to be sure which mapping is broken.. Not as professional advice.. but without more details

Comment: @RadimKöhler that is the enum, Role. it get saves as integer. in the database I see the value is ok, "1". any idea why? thanks

Comment: @RadimKöhler that is the enum, Role. I have removed the rest... it get saves as integer. in the database I see the value is ok, "1". any idea why? thanks

Comment: Sir, I wish I see what is wrong. Then I would give you the answer.. right now only these hints in the above comments. I guess it would be something very *stupid* ... because you can load it... so mapping is ok. If you check in Profiler, which value is updated! that could help us. If we will see that the value is 2, then some part of your infrastructure is doing changes. For this testing apply `DynamicUpdate();` in the class mapping == only changed cols will be UPDATED

Comment: @RadimKöhler - what helped is changing the custom type to Map(x => CustomType<Role>() instead of int, thank you, if you want to get rewarded, post a question so I will accept it. thanks for your time.

Comment: Great to see that you did it! I am so happy that you did not give up. NHibernate is amazing tool. If you think I helped I can put some findings into the answer. Good luck with NHibernate, amazing tool

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in comments, the point is, that we are all the time working with a session. It is so smart that even during read operation, it does keep track of all items by their ID.

If, any object is changed somehow *(e.g. for a rendering or transfering reasons)* and is still referenced by open session, it is managed as dirty one. When the `session.Fulsh()` is called (usually by default on transaction Commit() or even auto, depends on the FlushMode) any dirty object is persisted.

So, to avoid issuing the UPDATE statement the Entity mapping and its content must match. As at the end Shazam founded out, in this case the culprit was this mapping

```
// Map(x => x.Role).CustomType<int>();
Map(x => CustomType<Role>()
```

Comment: I think that I learned from your 2 first comments the most. I did not know about the dirty on flush. thanks again

Comment: Great if that helped anyhow. Enjoy NHibernate, simply awesome tool ;)